# Setting drop-down menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have made a drop down menu and got some styling issues with it. My code for drop down menu is

```
       <ul class="dd">
       <li><a href="main.php" >Home</a>
       </li>
       <li><a href="' . $user . '">Profile</a>
       </li>
       <li><a href="my_messages.php">Inbox' . $unread_numrows . '</a>
       </li> 
       <li><a href="#">Management</a>
       <ul>
       <li><a href="account_settings.php">Settings</a>
       </li>
       <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      </ul>';
```

**CSS**

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
       .dd {
         background-color:#BF3B3D;
         position: absolute;
         right:0px;
         top:0;
         margin-right: 4%;
       }  
       }

        @media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
        .dd {
          background-color:#BF3B3D;
          position: absolute;
          right:0px;
          top:0;
          margin-right: 10%;
       }  
       }
        @media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
        .dd {
          background-color:#BF3B3D;
          position: absolute;
          right:0px;
          top:0;
          margin-right: 25%;
        }
        }
         .dd li {
          border-radius: 4px;
          background-color: #BF3B3D;
          float: left;
          position: relative;
          list-style: none;
          top:8px;
          padding: 10px 5px 10px 5px;
         }
          .dd li:hover{
           background-color: #7A0709;
         }
          .dd li a{
            font-size: 14px;
            color:#ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #BF3B3D;
          }
           .dd li ul li{
            top: 14px; 
            border-radius: 4px;
          }
          .dd li:hover ul{
            background-color: #BF3B3D;
          }
           .dd li:hover a{
            background-color: #7A0709;
          }
          .dd li:hover li a{
             background-color:#BF3B3D;
          }
           .dd li ul{
            display: none;
          }
           .dd li:hover ul {
            display: block; 
            position: absolute;
          }
           .dd li:hover li {
            float: none;
          }
           .dd li ul li:hover a{
            background-color: #7A0709;
          }
```

Now when I hover over menu it's color changes and so for sub-menu's, but when sub-menu's are open under menu the color for that menu is also changed though I am rolling over sub-menu so when rolling over sub-menu I want only sub-menu's color changed and menu should go back to it's color. Also their appears to be some space between sub-menu and menu that took some of space inside menu I want to get rid of that space.

Answer (score 1):

To fix that hover effect problem use immediate children selector for main menu hover css. like this.

```
.dd > li:hover{
           background-color: #7A0709;
}
```

">" will only select immediate children only. so on sub menus will only effect by your other css hover.

to fix height problem you should provide top main menu a `display:block` and fixed height as you want. to help on that more, you better provide a fiddle.